# Modelling a capacitor on a PCB

Tags: capacitor, pcb, pcb-design

I want to design a "PCB capacitor". The goal is to detect the permittivity of the material surrounding the PCB. I am unsure how to design the electrodes of the capacitor in order to have the highest sensitivity. It will be a two layer PCB.

I basically have three designs in my mind, see attached image, but I have no idea which would be the best. I also dont know if I should use a ground plane, but I guess a ground plane would be contra productive, because it would block the field lines in the back, reducing the sensitivity.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first and most simple design is good. Two parallel areas with GND and the measuring-pin.

Look at the source of the Austrian "[Giesomat](https://www.ramser-elektro.at/shop/bausaetze-und-platinen/giesomat-kapazitiver-bodenfeuchtesensor-erdfeuchtesensor-unbeschichtet/)", the ramser-elektro guy has created the Capacitive soil moisture sensor.